# Problem with hiding modalviewcontroller using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, asihttprequest

I have a problem with hiding modalviewcontroller when I connect to server with ASIHttpRequest.
I connect in background thread and show modalview in main thread.
This is my code:

```
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loginServerRequest) withObject:nil];


    - (void)loginServerRequest {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://11.111.111.11/api/login"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:[AccountSettings getCompany] forKey:@"companyName"];
    [request setPostValue:[AccountSettings getEmail] forKey:@"email"];
    [request setPostValue:[AccountSettings getPassword] forKey:@"password"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:10];
    [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];
    [pool drain];
}
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideServerConnectView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    int status = [request responseStatusCode];
    NSLog(@"%i", status);
    if ([self.nibName isEqualToString:@"RootViewController"]) {
        if (status == 200) {
           //some code
        }
    }
}
- (void)hideServerConnectView {
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

If server responses immediately modalviewcontroller doesn't hide! 
If pass some seconds then everything is okay.
What's the problem??

---

I changed my code like this:

```
    [self loginServerRequest];
    ServerConnectView *viewC = [[ServerConnectView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:viewC.view];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewC animated:YES];
    [viewC release];

- (void)loginServerRequest {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://11.111.111.11/api/login"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:[AccountSettings getCompany] forKey:@"companyName"];
[request setPostValue:[AccountSettings getEmail] forKey:@"email"];
[request setPostValue:[AccountSettings getPassword] forKey:@"password"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:10];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
[self hideServerConnectView];
int status = [request responseStatusCode];
NSLog(@"%i", status);
if ([self.nibName isEqualToString:@"RootViewController"]) {
    if (status == 200) {
       //some code
    }
  }
}
- (void)hideServerConnectView {
   [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

And it didn't solve my problem.
Any ideas? Or something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing async and sync methods.

You set up the request as though it's an async request, but then call `[request startSynchronous];`.

Because of this, the delegate methods will not be called and your modal will not be dismissed.

The fix is to fire off the request async, using `[request startAsynchronous];`

This also means that you don't need to call `performSelectorInBackground` (or setup the autorelease pool in the `loginServerRequest` method).

Answer (score 0):

In your asynchronous version, move `[self hideServerConnectView];` just after `[self loginServerRequest];`

OR use `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait` to invoke `- (void)hideServerConnectView` since UI update must occur on the Main Thread.